# What is best practice to multiple API call in request module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, request

I want to make one more request with `result.Reference[i].resourceId` value.So please advise how to make second request within below code.

Example host will be

```
    var request = require('request');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var options = {
  url: 'http://host/xxxx/rest/domain/all',
  method:'GET'

};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var result = JSON.parse(body);

}

request(options, callback);


function count(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var result = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a call to `request()` within the callback? (Providing some other callback function for the second request, presumably.)

Comment: What is `result.Reference.length`? Are you trying to make a separate request for each `i`?

Comment: yes , Based on i value the request going call service.

Comment: Is `result.Reference[i].resourceId` an options object? What value should be passed to `request()` from `result.Reference[i].resourceId`?

Comment: result.Reference[i].resourceId will pass some alpha number id and that become http://host:8080/rest/'23445dfg-sdfrt45-234556df-xcdf34'/value

Comment: Are you trying to pass `result.Reference[i].resourceId` as first parameter to `request()` call?

Comment: yes , thats only one parameter going to append in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a closure for `i` within `for` loop using an immediately invoked function expression; pass `i` to function call, pass required variable from `result.Reference[i].resourceId` to IIFE; create a separate function to handle callback for the calls to `request` made within `for` loop

```
function handleResponse(error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
     // do stuff
   }
}

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var result = JSON.parse(body);
    for(var i=0;i<result.Reference.length;i++) {
      (function(id) {
        request(id, handleResponse)
      // pass value from `result.Reference[i].resourceId` to IIFE here
      })(result.Reference[i].resourceId); 
    }
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: Thank you. But some change in the url itself. Please see question and advise.

Comment: Yes, you can use same pattern at Answer. Pass `calloptions` to IIFE within `for` loop, substitute `count` for `handleResponse` at call to `request()` within IIFE.